# Best security framework for c# desktop applications?

Tags: c#, .net, security, windows

I need an authentication service and authorization service for c# desktop applications.

Comment: I need something like ASP.Net membership or Rhino security (on this occasion can i use it for desktop apps?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go with Windows Identity Foundation (WIF), this is a claims based authentication system that works across all (at least most) MS platforms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx

Comment: In a quick look i found this depends mainly on windows authentication services such as active directory, but i need some thing more optimizable and can depend on database or Something like this.

Comment: WIF requires a STS - Security Token Service, this can be active directory but it does not have to be, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'optimizable' & if by 'database' you mean a typical 'Users' table you, all you need is your custom-fit STS (to your database/business logic) Security Token Service (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2010/08/10/windows-identity-foundation-wif-by-example-part-i-how-to-get-started.aspx or http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4C09FFE4-43DD-4FCC-BE35-C897C9BC4386 page 37 or 75). WIF is not tied to AD or windows auth or anything, e.g. AD on Windows is just a good target to implement a 80% solution for, in contrast to e.g. your custom db.

Comment: Thanks very much, but the big problem (WINDOWS XP NOT SUPPORTED), are there any other options!